# How can fix and strengthen a linen closet shelf?

Tags: support, shelf

The shelves in our linen closet are loose (pics below).

I plan to fix them by installing angle brackets. One side of the bracket will be on the loose frame, and the other on the wooden frame attached to the wall. My plan (if possible) is to fix it in a simple way (e.g. not needing holes in the drywall), as we don't plan to put a lot of stress on the structure (just linen).

I plan to use [these brackets](https://www.bunnings.com.au/carinya-30-x-30-x-17-x-1-8mm-white-round-angle-bracket-12-pack_p3962550) (size is 30 x 30 x 17 x 1.8mm) and [these 20m screws](https://www.bunnings.com.au/zenith-6g-x-20mm-gold-passivated-type-17-countersunk-head-timber-screws-100-pack_p2409088).

Is this approach sensible? Any other tips or advice?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, those repair brackets. will work well.

It may make sense to use screws into the wall mounted wood (cleat), but to drill through the perpendicular wood (beam) and bolt the brackets on there instead (machine screw and nut)  especially if the wood is only 19mm thick. otherwise screwing from both sides may have the screws colliding in the wood.

Comment: IDK, seems to me simply toe nailing a couple of nails through the shelf support into the wall beam would be sufficient and easily hidden with some caulk and paint.  Obvs the support would need to be lifted into the proper position before nailing.

Comment: Thank you, @jasen. I appreciate that you are also helping me to learn the proper vocabulary (beam + cleat). Good idea about the bolts.